# How to parse string and make string with tags from json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using next.js. I have json file with a string:

```
{
  "title":"Just a text with <b>accent</b> inside",
}
```

I want get this string and return a string with `<b>` tag inside.
There is my function:

```
function parseTitle(title) {
  let match = title.match(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/);
  let prev = match[0];
  let next = match[1];
  let result = title.replace(new RegExp(prev, 'g'), '<b>' + next + '</b>');
  return (
    result
  )
}
```

And, when I try to use it:

```
<h1>{parseTitle(votingInfo.title)}</h1>
```

Of course, I get a string without tags:

```
Just a text with <b>accent</b> inside
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You accent as a output ?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```js
const App = () => {
    const str = "Just a text with <b>accent</b> inside";

    function parseTitle(title) {
      let match = title.match(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/);
      let prev = match[0];
      let next = match[1];
      let result = title.replace(new RegExp(prev, 'g'), '<b>' + next + '</b>');
      return (
        result
      )
    }

    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: parseTitle(str) }}>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I thought I'd understood your question, but it seems you weren't asking this. In any case, your `parseTitle` function doesn't do anything — it just returns the string argument unchanged.

Here's an annotated version:

```
function parseTitle(title) {
    let match = title.match(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/)
    let prev = match[0] // "<b>accent</b>" (the full match)
    let next = match[1] // "accent" (the part of the match in parentheses)

    // replace "<b>accent</b>" with "<b>" + "accent" + "</b>"
    // (i.e. the exact same string)
    let result = title.replace(new RegExp(prev, 'g'), '<b>' + next + '</b>')

    // return the unchanged string
    return result
}
```

---

**Original answer**

The logic of `parseTitle` is wrong. You can implement this using regex lookbehind and lookahead:

```js
function parseTitle(title) {
    return title.match(/(?<=<b>)[^<]+(?=<\/b>)/)?.[0] ?? ''
}

console.log(parseTitle("Just a text with <b>accent</b> inside")) // "accent"
```

`(?<=<b>)` matches an opening `<b>` tag *before* the match; `[^<]+` matches anything that isn't an opening angle bracket; `(?=<\/b>)` matches a closing `</b>` tag *after* the match. Grabbing `[0]` from a `RegExpMatchArray` returns the whole matched substring.

The function will return an empty string in case it fails to match anything in the `title` passed to it.